# How to insert a outlook mail msg as an element in a row in PostgresSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-mail

I need to develop a system in which a requester will upload an outlook *.msg file having approval for the request. How can I save(Insert) this *.msg file in PostgreSql row of approval table. The business logic is developed in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You should store email messages as `bytea` fields, because they might be in any text encoding. So you would:

- Create a `ByteArrayInputStream` that points to the message file; and
- Use a JDBC parameterized `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, inserting the data with `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(...)` into a `bytea` field.

See:

- [JDBC Tutorial - prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [PgJDBC - storing binary data](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/92/binary-data.html)